# Search and Open Word documents from excel

Tags: vba

I am creating an excel sheet to search through a database for word (.docx) documents and i want to then open them. I am able to find the file and open it if it is a spreadsheet. but i cant get word documents to open? I get a mismatch error at the "objWord.documents.Open xFile" line, any answers??

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call FindFile
End Sub

Sub FindFile()

Dim xFile As File
Dim xFolder As Folder
    Set Fsys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ObjFolder = Fsys.GetFolder("File Folder")

For Each xFolder In ObjFolder.SubFolders
    If FindFiles(xFolder) = True Then Exit Sub
    If FindFolder(xFolder) = True Then Exit Sub
Next
    Set Fsys = Nothing
    MsgBox "File not found.."

End Sub

Function FindFolder(FolderPath As Folder) As Boolean
Dim RootFolder As Folder
For Each RootFolder In FolderPath.SubFolders
    If FindFiles(RootFolder) = True Then
        FindFolder = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    Call FindFolder(RootFolder)
Next
End Function     
Function FindFiles(xFolder As Folder) As Boolean

Dim xFile As File
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files

      FindFiles = False

    If LCase(xFile.Name) = LCase(Range("B2").Value) Then
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
        objWord.documents.Open xFile

        FindFiles = True

              FindFiles = True
        Exit Function
    End If

Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

So through much investigation, the answer was to save the file path in a cell and then create a new sub to open word documents from the file path. Simple but see below if anyone is interested.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call FindFile
Call Open_Word_Document
End Sub

Sub FindFile()

Dim xFile As File
Dim xFolder As Folder

Range("B9").ClearContents

Set Fsys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ObjFolder = Fsys.GetFolder("Folder Path")

For Each xFolder In ObjFolder.SubFolders
    If FindFiles(xFolder) = True Then Exit Sub
    If FindFolder(xFolder) = True Then Exit Sub
Next

If IsEmpty(Range("B9").Value) = True Then

MsgBox "Diary doesnt exist, have you had your head checked lately!"
End
End If
End Sub

Function FindFolder(FolderPath As Folder) As Boolean
Dim RootFolder As Folder
For Each RootFolder In FolderPath.SubFolders
    If FindFiles(RootFolder) = True Then
        FindFolder = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    Call FindFolder(RootFolder)
Next
End Function

Function FindFiles(xFolder As Folder) As Boolean

Dim xFile As File
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files

      FindFiles = False

    If LCase(xFile.Name) = LCase(Range("B8").Value) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = xFile.Path


        FindFiles = True

        Exit Function
    End If

Next
End Function

Sub Open_Word_Document()
'Opens a Word Document from Excel

' Define Word object.
Dim objWord As Object
' Create Word instance.
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'Load the file named in Cell B9.
objWord.Documents.Open Range("B9").Value
'Make Word visible.
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```